# What is $2^{7!}\bmod{2987}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Find the remainder when $2^{7!}$ is divided by $2987$.

I tried to factorise $2987$ to make it simple but it was in vain.

Comment: Did you at least discover that $2987=29\cdot103$?

Comment: Yes that's why factorising it makes no sense

Comment: @MayankJha: What about that factorization you do find particularly nonsensical?

Comment: Are you perhaps supposed to be studying the Euler totient function?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_theorem

Answer (score 9):

Hint: The unique prime factorization of $2987$ is,

$$2987=29\times 103$$

Now, use Fermat's Little Theorem to reduce the exponent and get the remainder modulo $29$ and $103$.

Combine the results using Chinese Remainder Theorem.

---

Alternatively, you can use Euler's totient function to compute $\phi(2987)$ and then use Euler's Totient theorem but that might result in tedious calculations and we being lazy never want to do it the tedious way. :P

Comment: Well, powers of two are easy enough when they are less than 2987.

Comment: @nayrb, I suck at mental arithmetic, so I would disagree. :P

Comment: Leasing you are brilliant you have the most convincing answer to that question.

Comment: @MayankJha, I hope the answer helped you. :) P.s - I'm not at all brilliant. In fact, I'm the dumbest in my group.

Comment: @MayankJha See my answer for one way to do this using only very simple mental arithmetic.

Comment: @BillDubuque, How is my answer different from yours other than the fact that I gave a hint while you wrote down the full solution?

Comment: @Prasun The point of my answer is to show how to compute it with *purely mental arithmetic*.

Answer (score 9):

$2^{\large 7!}\!\pmod{\color{brown}{29}87}\,$ can be computed using *only* simple mental arithmetic.

Note that  $\ \color{brown}{29}\!\mid\! 87,\,$ i.e. $\, 29\cdot 3 = 87\ $ so $\ 2987 = 29(100\!+\!3) = 29\cdot 103$

Since $\, p = 29,103\,$ are prime, we can use little Fermat to reduce exponents, i.e.

$(1)\qquad\qquad\ \ N \equiv n\pmod{p\!-\!1}\ \Rightarrow\ 2^{N}\!\equiv 2^{n}\pmod p$

${\rm mod}\,\ \ 28\!:\ 7! \equiv 0\ $ by $\ 7,4\mid 7!\,\Rightarrow\, 28=7\cdot 4\mid 7!$

${\rm mod}\ 102\!:\, 7! \equiv (7\cdot 5\cdot 3)(6\cdot 4\cdot 2)\equiv 105(14\!+\!34)\equiv 3(14) \equiv 42,\, $ so,  $ $ applying $(1)$

${\rm mod}\ 29\!:\ \ \ x\equiv  2^{\large 7!}\equiv 2^{0}\equiv\color{#c00} 1$

${\rm mod}\ 103\!:\ x\equiv 2^{\large 7!}\equiv 2^{42}.\ $  Let's compute this power:

$\qquad\ 2^{10}=1024\equiv 1030\!-\!6\equiv -6,\,$ so $\,2^{11}\equiv -12\,$ so $\,2^{21}\equiv (-6)(-12) \equiv 72\equiv -31$

$\ \Rightarrow\  2^{42} \equiv (2^{21})^2\equiv (-31)^2\equiv (1\!+\!30)^2 \equiv 1 + 2(30)+9(-3)\equiv \color{blue}{34}$

Finally we apply $ $ CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem:

${\rm mod}\ 29\!:\ \color{#c00}1\equiv x\equiv \color{blue}{34}\!+\!103j\equiv 5\!+\!16j\!\iff\! 16j\equiv -4\!\iff\! 4j\equiv -1\equiv 28\!\iff\! j\equiv\color{#0a0} 7$

So we deduce $\ x = 34\! +\! 103(\color{#0a0}7\!+\!29k)\, =\, 755 + 2987k$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not make use of *Fermat's Little Theorem*.

---

**The Algorithm:**

- Input: $x=2,e=7!,n=2987$
- Output: $y=1$
- Repeat until $e=0$:

  - If $e\equiv1\pmod2$ then set $y=yx\bmod{n}$
  - Set $x=x^2\bmod{n}$
  - Set $e=\left\lfloor\frac{e}{2}\right\rfloor$

**C Implementation:**

```
int PowMod(int x,int e,int n)
{
    int y = 1;
    while (e > 0)
    {
        if (e & 1)
            y = (y*x)%n;
        x = (x*x)%n;
        e >>= 1;
    }
    return y;
}

int result = PowMod(2,5040,2987); // 755
```

**Intermediate Output:**

```
   x   |   e   |   y
-------|-------|-------
     2 |  5040 |     1
     4 |  2520 |     1
    16 |  1260 |     1
   256 |   630 |     1
  2809 |   315 |     1
  1814 |   157 |  2809
  1909 |    78 |  2691
   141 |    39 |  2691
  1959 |    19 |    82
  2373 |     9 |  2327
   634 |     4 |  1995
  1698 |     2 |  1995
   749 |     1 |  1995
  2432 |     0 |   755
```

---

Please note that the complexity is $O(\log_2e)$, resulting in $\lceil\log_27!\rceil=13$ iterations.

Answer (score -1):

[Computational answer](https://cloud.sagemath.com/projects/6955a6ad-cd83-480f-838f-c368d4bc2acb/files/2987.sagews)=755 (Cloud Sage)

Edit: 7! not 71. Sorry