# Fermats little theorem, $p$ is not a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Calculate the remainder $$ r \equiv 37^{877} \bmod{323} $$

I don't know how to follow this up since $323$ is not a prime number.

Comment: $323 = 17\cdot 19$

Comment: How you ever heard about Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: One idea is to use Euler's generalization of Fermat's Little Theorem.  More tedious but possible is to carry out the computation for moduli that are factors of 323, then piece the results together via Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please review [ask].  Your posts will be easier to read if you use [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ syntax to format math notation.

Comment: Related:  [What is $2^{7!} \bmod 2987$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1221208/what-is-27-bmod2987).

Comment: Have a look at [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand) and som other posts which are [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/81228).

Answer (score 2):

$323=17\cdot19$

Now $37\equiv -1\pmod{19}\implies37^{877}\equiv(-1)^{877}\equiv-1\ \ \ \ (1)$

and $37\equiv3\pmod{17}\implies37^{877}\equiv3^{877}\pmod{17}$ and $877\equiv13\pmod{17-1}$

Using Fermat's Little Theorem, $3^{877}\equiv3^{13}\pmod{17}$

$3^4\equiv-4\pmod{17}\implies3^{12}=(3^4)^3\equiv(-4)^3\equiv4$

$\implies3^{13}=3\cdot3^{12}\equiv3\cdot4\equiv12\pmod{17}\ \ \ \ (2)$

Now apply CRT on $(1),(2)$

Comment: Thanks, but after 'and 877≡13(mod177−1)' I get totally lost, can't understand why you do that.

Comment: @mathematician31415: I fixed both typos.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get what happens at  877≡13(mod17−1), is that some specific formula we use?

Comment: okay I did it and got to -1977 mod 323 ≡ -39 mod 323, which I think is the correct answer. Many thanks to all who helped!